# Dynamic form Angular issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

I have written this code online [dynamic form jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhkedykz/15/)

The total and grand total are not auto updating. I had a more simple example before and it was working with a single model item, but then I made an array and now it won't work. My real program I am building is going to have many more fields and I am trying to create a pre-example to show it will work. Can someone quickly see what dumb thing I am forgetting?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.a">
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.b">
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.c">
          <label>Total: </label><label ng-bind="total(item)"></label>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>
    <label>Grand Total: </label><label ng-bind="grandTotal()"></label>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
      {
        a: 0, b: 0, c: 0
      },
      {
        a: 0, b: 0, c: 0
      }];

    $scope.total = function(item) { 
        var result = item.a * item.b * item.c;

      return isNaN(result) ? 0 : result;
    };

    $scope.grandTotal = function() { 
        var result = 0;

      angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
        result += $scope.total(item);
      });

      return isNaN(result) ? "" : result.toString();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-bind` should be without `$scope`. You don't need to mention `$scope` in view bindings, it directly refers to `$scope`/`this`(context) of controller.

Other than that additionally change all input's `ng-bind` to `ng-model` to enable two way binding over all input fields.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.a">
<input type="text" ng-model="item.b">
<input type="text" ng-model="item.c">

ng-bind="total(item)"
```

[**Forked JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4L80g1pg/)

Comment: Good catch, but even with `$scope` removed, I don't see it displaying the totals

Comment: He should change the `ng-bind` to `ng-model` for his `<input>`.  Add this to your answer.

Comment: I updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lhkedykz/15/. It still doesn't work. It calls my total function at the start but never again after I start typing in values.

Comment: Zach please write up answer and I will mark it answer.

Comment: @Zach Thanks for heads up as well. after answering I got busy with something else. And then I edited comment & saw fiddle. Thereafter I realize about `ng-bind` are there on `input` fields.. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.a">
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" ng-bind="item.a">
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lhkedykz/17/